# How to maintain my column width on a div with display: table?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a view of tabular data.  Here is what my `html` looks like:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

And the `css` which is totally predictable:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes I want to show extra info for a row.  I want a 'more' link to add info below the current `row`.  When I do this, my `columns` are not aligned.

I have tried adding ad additional `row` with `display: block` below the expanded `row` and it messes up the alignment.

How else can I do this?  How does `div` `table` alignment work?